# Risks in switching from 'Copy always' to 'Copy if newer'

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In order to avoid rebuilding the libraries that have not been touched I'm changing *Copy to Output Directory* for some files from *Copy always* to *Copy if newer* in some c# projects.

The files whose setting is changed have their *Build Action* set to one of *Content*, *Embedded Resource*, or *Resource*.

What are the risks accompanied with this?

Comment: Why do you copy those types of resources at all? They are embedded in you assembly...

Comment: I'm improving the existing build behaviour. I'm looking for changes with least impact.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Besides this probably being obsolete (e.g. due to resources being embedded), the only risk I could think of right now would be the fact that you could use outdated files in case some program changes something without updating the file's timestamp (or modifying this timestamp). For example, you might do some local changes to a file, then revert its contents using some kind of file versioning system (like SVN or HG). It's then possible that Visual Studio won't notice the reverted file and it might not copy it.